# Lazarus console app can't connect to mysql - ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lazarus

I have one console app in Lazarus and my OS is Ubuntu 16.04.
I can connect to db in Lazarus IDE.
But when I try to connect to database in my console app my exeption is :

```
Can not load default MySQL library ("libmysqlclient.so.18" or "libmysqlclient.so"). Check your installation.
```

Why I can't connect in console app but in IDE I can ?
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add:

```
{$LinkLib libmysqlclient.so}
```

and find the mysql or mariadb version client lib and copy to folder project or `/usr/libs/libmysqlclient.so.xx` xx is version

Answer (score 0):

I'm Add :

```
{$LinkLib libmysqlclient.so}
```

after uses then :

copy `libmysqlclient.so` by this name `/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18`.

It's done.